# Unable to call a javascript function onchange of a Select tag in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a JS function onchange from a select tag in MVC. It doesnt seem to be working. Here is the code.

In the Homepage view I have the following div containing the select tag

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- beginning of search block -->
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="select1" name="select1" onchange="populate(this.id,'select2')">
                <option value="Residential">RESIDENTIAL</option>
                <option value="Commercial">COMMERCIAL</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2"></select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

In the _Layout page I am referencing the Scripts folder with

```
<script src="~/Scripts/searchform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The javascript function that I am calling is

```
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  if (s1.value == "Residential") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "1bhk|1BHK", "2bhk|2BHK", "3bhk|3BHK", "4bhk|4BHK", "4+bhk|4+BHK"];
  }
  if (s1.valueOf == "Commercial") {
    var optionArray = ["|", "500sft|500SFT", "1000sft|1000SFT", "1500sft|1500SFT", "2000sft|2000SFT", "2500sft|2500SFT"];
  }

  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

I am unable to figure out why the function is not being called.

Comment: some browsers can't update the select element "innerhtml" property (anyone said ie?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second checking you are using `s1.valueOf` instead of `s1.value`

Your function will be

```
function populate(s1, s2) {
     var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
     var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
     s2.innerHTML = "";
     if (s1.value == "Residential") {
          var optionArray = ["|", "1bhk|1BHK", "2bhk|2BHK", "3bhk|3BHK", "4bhk|4BHK", "4+bhk|4+BHK"];
      }
      if (s1.value == "Commercial") {
          var optionArray = ["|", "500sft|500SFT", "1000sft|1000SFT", "1500sft|1500SFT", "2000sft|2000SFT", "2500sft|2500SFT"];
      }

      for (var option in optionArray) {
          var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
          var newOption = document.createElement("option");
          newOption.value = pair[0];
          newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
          s2.options.add(newOption);
      }   
   }
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Thanks Razack. It is working now. But I do not understand why because initially I did code it using only 'value' and not 'valueOf' and it was not working. Then I changed it to 'valueOf' as prompted by the intellisense to check if that would make it work, which also did not work. Now I have changed it back to 'value' and its working!! The only thing I did different was i rendered it with IE before rendering with chrome. What am I missing here?